# How to get specific data from mysql to a php web page?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, echo

First, I'm not asking how to display all records from a table, but a specific information.
I've seen similar questions about how to display all data, but it doesn't help me when it's about choosing specific data and actually **showing it** on the site.

I'll explain better with an exemple :

I have a table named *ressources* with three columns: **name, x, y**.

I have this row: *anonymous, 12, 14*.

How do I get the **x** or **y** value by only knowing the **name**?
I've seen this kind of SQL request:

```
mysqli_query($connexion,"SELECT * FROM ressources WHERE name = 'anonymous' LIMIT 1");
```

But my problem here is: how do I display it with echo?

Here's what I mean:

```
echo "You have " + $x + " cows and " + $y " horses."
```

while:

$x : x

$y : y

name : anonymous

Comment: Its really a simple thing, actually fundamentals of the topic, what about reading some wikis or watching some tutorials?

Comment: I've seen some, but I can't figure out this one. Really. I always get "How to display table" not "display simple data"

Comment: Sidenote: I doubt you want to do math with the `+` in `echo "You have " + $x + " cows and " + $y " horses."` - I think you come from a JS background. This is "PHP"; use a period. *They're two different animals altogether* ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you query SELECT statements, you need to fetch them before making any echoes:

```
// assign it on a variable
$query = mysqli_query($connexion,"SELECT * FROM ressources WHERE name = 'anonymous' LIMIT 1");
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
// fetch the results, since you're expecting a single row, no need to loop
// this returns an associative array

// then as usual just a normal variable assignment.    
$x = $result['x'];
$y = $result['y'];
$name = $result['anonymous'];

// then your echoes
echo "You have " . $x . " cows and " . $y . " horses.";
// (concatenation in PHP is `.`)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, it's fetch_assoc(); or mysql_fetch_assoc()?

Comment: @ChaosLord its the same, i just use the object oriented interface. mysqli supports both

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch and then echo

```
     $result=mysqli_query($connexion,"SELECT * FROM ressources WHERE name = 'anonymous' LIMIT 1");

       // Associative array
       $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       echo 'You have '.$row["x"].'cows and '.$row["y"].' horses';
```